# Clamping wires into service panel

Tags: electrical-panel

Have three #10 solid (loose, no sheathing) to feed into service panel. Since there is no sheathing what kind of wire clamp is allowed?

Comment: What area of the world (or US) are you in? What is the rating of the wires (e.g. THHN?) Code varies in different places. I think you will probably need to run the wires in some kind of conduit (metallic or non-metallic) which then attaches to the service panel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to route #8 THHN wires into an existing panel](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/257892/how-to-route-8-thhn-wires-into-an-existing-panel)

Answer (score 4):

If you are referring to hot or neutral wires, then you have a misconception about how single wires are used.  They must be inside a conduit wiring method such as EMT or PVC, the conduit must be continuous the whole length, and the conduit must be built out complete before any wires are pulled in.

If these are all ground wires (GECs or retrofit grounds) then they can be stapled or otherwise secured, and just brought in as a group into a Romex style cable clamp.